# Time -Domain to Frequency Domain

Tags: fft, time-frequency, frequency-domain

I am constructing a MFCC and come to a section which is kind of confusing me.

It is:

Step 4: Fast Fourier Transform

and has this equation:

[image]

Now I understand that FFT needs to be carried out, I just don't understand where the values are meant for:

h(t)

x(t)

H(w)

x(w)

Up to now, I have:

- Inputted the raw signal (vector)
- Pre-emphasis filtering on the signal
- Carried out "Framing" (vector of vectors)
- Computed Hamming Window

It's just this step I am unsure of.

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention they mean the following:

$x(t)$ = Input in the time domain

$h(t)$ = Filter impulse response (time domain)

$H(w)$ = Filter frequency response

$X(w)$ = Input in the frequency domain

In the equation that you wrote the two "*" symbols mean different things.  In the time domain it is convolution, in the frequency domain it is multiplication.  The equation is just saying that convolution in the time domain (which is how you do time domain filtering) is equivalent to multiplication in the frequency domain.

Comment: So basically, I have a 2D vector containing values (up to the hamming window) so are these values x(t)? If so, then hat is h(t) because I only have 1 set of values, not 2? So this equation is basically telling me to get the FFT results of x(t) ...?

Comment: So basically y(w) = FFT[x(t)]?

Comment: Please describe what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Hey, basically, I'm trying to implement an MFCC and I am reading this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.4083.pdf and in "Step 4" it describes the Fourier Transform.. I have followed the steps up until this point but am getting confused at this stage. Thank you for your help, it means a lot

Comment: $x(t)$, in this case, is each frame of data that has already had the Hamming window applied to it.  Step 4 is simply telling you to calculate the FFT of each frame of data in step 5.  In step 5 you filter the frames with the Mel filters.  Presumably you calculate the frequency domain response of the filters as well, and then you just multiply $X(w)$ (your transformed frames), by $H(w)$ (the Mel filters' frequency response).

Comment: In step 4, I just simply take the FFT of each frame of data that has already had the Hamming window, in step 5 multiply x(w) (The FFT of each frame) by H(w) the Mel Filters frequency response? Is that correct? Sorry, my head is struggling with this.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Mind you, I am not an expert on the topic.  I just scanned the paper, but I believe that that is correct.

Comment: One last question (Sorry)! You mentioned the convolution of this equation, that the "*" mean different things. Therefore, do I have to calculate the convolution as well? I.e. the equation AFTER the "="?

Comment: No.  Multiplying in the frequency domain is the same thing as convolving in the time domain.  You will multiply in the frequency domain instead of convolving in the time domain.

Comment: Sorry about this. You mention "h(t) = Filter impulse response (time domain)" But I have not calculated the Filter Impulse Response - Does this mean I should calculate this on my input signal? Confused

Comment: With all due respect, you really need to take a DSP class or buy a textbook and work through it.  I can tell you what to do, but you don't have the background to understand what I, or anyone else, says.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to learn this. It's not an easy subject but I do not want to give up. It's just this one step that is causing confusion. I need to do step 5 (in the paper) before I can do step 4 then? I re-read your comment above.. "In step 5 you filter the frames with the Mel filters. Presumably you calculate the frequency domain response of the filters as well, and then you just multiply X(w) (your transformed frames), by H(w) (the Mel filters' frequency response)."

Comment: Here are the steps as I recall: break up your data into "frames".  Multiply each frame of data by a Hamming window of the exact same length.  FFT the frames.  Multiply the FFT'ed frames by the Mel filters' frequency response ($H(w)$).  $H(w)$ (there will be one for each Mel filter) must be the same size as the frames of data.

Comment: Ahh I get it now. After I have done this, I can then convert the signal back to time using the DCT and therefore have completed the MFCC? Also, do you know of any books / online materials that could help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Yes.  No, I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the MFCC algorithm.  If you're looking for general DSP information I think there are a couple threads that talk about useful material.